# Using the GUI to access data bindings in MvvmCross Wpf project causes errors

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvmcross

I'm getting errors when trying to use the gui to do any kind of data binding using MvvmCross in a Wpf project.  My WP8 project works fine.  I can replicate this with an "empty" project.

The process I followed

- Visual Studio 2012, latest version of Xamarin.
- Create a new Portable Class Library project (Profile 104 or 78)
- Create a new Wpf   project
- Add MvvmCross to both projects using nuget
- Add a reference to Core from the Wpf project

The project will now run perfectly, but I cant use the gui to set bindings.

- Open FirstView.xaml
- Click either TextBox
- Go to Properties
- Click the small square next to Text
- Select "Create New Binding"

I get the following error, and the Xaml designer fails with a FileNotFoundException

> Could not load the assembly mvvmtest.wpf because the following errors
>   occurred:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Followed by a load more similar errors.

I've spent hours googling and trying different approaches and I'm still no further forward.

Comment: Did you reference the System.Core assembly in your project?

Comment: System.Core v4.0.30319 is automatically referenced in the Wpf project, neither the Core or WP8 projects reference it

Comment: its the false version, u need 2.0.5.0. Mvvmcross should add these automatically. Did you install mvvmcross over NuGet?

Comment: Yes, this one (http://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross/) as recommended in one of the n+1 videos.  The app runs, I just cant use the xaml designer to data bind